# What does do the bases of the eigenvectors of a 2x2 matrix say about the nature of the matrix?

Tags: matrices

Hi this is question I'm having trouble for while preparing for my test.

I have matrix:
R = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

I found it to have eigenvalues of -1 and 1
for 1 the basis for the eigenspace I found is 
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}
for -1 it is
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}

Therefore the basis of eigenvectors are 
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix} ,& \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}

I was wondering what this says about the nature of the matrix R?

Comment: It means many things; could you be more specific about what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for specifically, but maybe you are having some conceptual difficulty visualizing what eigenvectors and eigenvalues "mean." Perhaps this [website](http://setosa.io/ev/eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues/) would help.

In this particular case you have two 1-dimensional eigenspaces corresponding to the two eigenvalues of $R$. Try drawing these eigenspaces as lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$; When the matrix $R$ acts on a vector in the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$, it flips the direction of the vector without stretching or compressing it. When $R$ acts on an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $+1$, it does absolutely nothing! Since any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ can be expressed in terms of the eigenbasis you gave, the matrix $R$ acts on $v$ by flipping the direction of one of its components, and leaving the other one unchanged.